# How to adjust figure size when using plotyy?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to adjust the figure size when using plotyy:

```
clc;
clear all;

t = 0:.1:4*pi;
y = sin(t);

figure(1);
set(gcf,'units','inches','renderer', 'painters');
pos = get(gcf,'pos');
set(gcf,'Units','inches',...
    'Position',[pos(1) pos(2) 4 2]);
plot(t,y)
xlabel('Time(s)')
ylabel('y(t)')
title('Sin function')
legend('y=sin(t)')
axis([0 t(end) -1.5 1.5])
set(gca,...
    'Units','normalized',...
    'YTick',-1.5:.5:1.5,...
    'XTick',0:t(end)/4:t(end),...
    'FontUnits','points',...
    'FontWeight','normal',...
    'FontSize',9,...
    'FontName','Times')
set(gca, 'Position', get(gca, 'OuterPosition') - ...
    get(gca, 'TightInset') * [-1 0 1 0; 0 -1 0 1; 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1]);

figure(2);
set(gcf,'units','inches','renderer', 'painters');
pos = get(gcf,'pos');
set(gcf,'Units','inches',...
    'Position',[pos(1) pos(2) 4 2]);
[haxes,hline1,hline2]=plotyy(t,y,t,t);
ylabel(haxes(1),'sin(t)')
ylabel(haxes(2),'45degree')
xlabel(haxes(1),'Time(s)')
title('Sin function')
set(haxes,...
    'Units','normalized',...
    'FontUnits','points',...
    'FontWeight','normal',...
    'FontSize',9,...
    'FontName','Times')
set(haxes(1), 'Position', get(haxes(1), 'OuterPosition') - ...
    get(haxes(1), 'TightInset') * [-1 0 1 0; 0 -1 0 1; 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 1]-...
    get(haxes(2), 'TightInset') * [0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0; 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 0]);
```

The example indicates that the procedure works well for plot but not for plotyy. It seems that when I use plot, TightInset takes into account the text on the bottom and on the top (as it should), but it doesn't take them into account when I use plotyy. But I don't understand why this is the case and how to fix it. Any ideas?

[Code below is related to my comment to the chosen answer]

```
figure(3);
set(gcf,'units','inches','renderer', 'painters');
pos = get(gcf,'pos');
set(gcf,'Units','inches',...
    'Position',[pos(1) pos(2) 4 2]);
plot(t,y,'b');
set(gca,'YColor','b')
xlabel('Time(s)')
ylabel('y(t)')
title('Sin function')
axis([0 t(end) -1.5 1.5]);
set(gca,...
    'Units','normalized',...
    'YTick',-1.5:.5:1.5,...
    'XTick',0:t(end)/4:t(end),...
    'FontUnits','points',...
    'FontWeight','normal',...
    'FontSize',9,...
    'FontName','Times')
axesPosition = get(gca,'Position');  
hNewAxes = axes('Position',axesPosition,...
    'Color','none',...           
    'YLim',[0 10],...            
    'YAxisLocation','right',...  
    'XTick',[],...               
    'Box','off');                
set(gca,'YColor',[0 .5 0]);
ylabel(hNewAxes,'45degree');
hold all
plot(hNewAxes,t,t,'color',[0 .5 0]);
hold off
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I try to avoid `plotyy` because there is always a property which doesn't behave as expected. If I need I usually create the second `axes` and set the properties by hand, copying what I need from the first `axes` of course, and linking a few properties.

If you look at the code for `plotyy` you will see that it does the same ... with some extra.

A nice extra is how it tries to match the ticks on both `y` axes, even when their span is different (but you could copy that part out and still use a manual dual axes solution).

Another extra, and what I suspect is responsible for the behavior you observed, is that it sets listeners and callback to readjust the `position` properties of both axes. Somewhere down the line it must kill some automatic readjustment of the `axes` because if you notice in your code, even before you tried to change the `position` manually, the `axes` were not readjusted when you called `xlabel` and `title` (as they are normally when you do that on a standard single `axes`).

This is why the `TightInset` you try to use to readjust your `axes` does not work ... because the `axes` were not readjusted when you added the text objects, (and so the vertical `TightInset` is wrong).

---

Now for your case, fortunately this only seem to affect the vertical part of the `TightInset`, so a quick workaround to get everything tight as in your first figure is to use the `OuterPosition` property for the vertical part (after getting the margin from `TightInset` for the horizontal part).

So in your code just replace your last call to `set(haxes,'Position', ...)` with:

```
margin = get(haxes(1),'TightInset') * [0;0;1;0] ;
set(haxes,'OuterPosition',[-margin 0 1+margin 1])
```

and everything should be tight again ;-)

Comment: Perfect! I have also tried out your other suggestion of setting another axis manually. Surprisingly, there was no need to adjust the position to get everything tight at all! I have absolutely no idea why this "magically" happened. Do you know why this happened?  (Since I cannot put a code here, I have added it to the question)